# Mongoid group and count by week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, aggregation-framework, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid6

In a Rails app with mongoid, given a collection with a created_at field, how would you return the number of records created for each week ?

I found somewhere a trick to add

```
def created_at_week
  created_at.strftime('W%W %Y')
end
```

so I can do something like `.group_by(&:week)` but this seems quite slow, I'd rather the database did the count for me instead of parsing everything in memory.

Is there a simple way to do that or do I need a map-reduce/aggregation query ?

I need to generate a table whose rows are the weeks between `start_date` and `end_date`, and whose columns are various collection/scopes.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: Actually my DB wasn't too big so the the `.group_by(&:week)` remained an option for me and I didn't look more into this matter. I'd be happy to upvote and accept other solutions.